# I have a very large library of older operating systems and was wondering if I could publicly distribute them

Tags: software

Over the years I have built up a huge collection of VHD's and ISO's basically images of Microsoft's OS. Server 2003 and back. I was wondering if it could start some sort of public database of these for people to download free of charge. These images contain no product keys or other methods of activation, I was simply going to put them out there because I have been in the same position trying to track down media for a OS, because I lost my copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend not doing this. Under the [Copyright Term Extension Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act) a copyright for a product is valid up to 95 years.

Even though you do not provide keys for the said products, you are not allowed to redistribute them. I recommend checking the related EULA's for the images you have.